# Hidden wp-admin use htaccess

Tags: wordpress

I want to change wp-admin to admin_panel using .htaccess file and when visit link admin_panel, it displays the contents of wp-admin, but when visit link wp-admin, it will notice not found

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms/wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^admin_panel/(.*) /cms/wp/wp-admin/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin /cms/wp/nothing_404_404 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /cms/wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

It not working, all url wp-admin or admin_panel result not found both.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-the-admin-url-or-wp-admin-to-secure-login check it here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea why you are trying to accomplish this only using .htaccess file but let me show you the correct way to change the admin directory.

If there is a specific reason why you want it to be done only using .htaccess file please let me know however I am not even sure if it is possible.

**Steps:**

1. Add constant to `wp-confing.php`

   ```
   define('WP_ADMIN_DIR', '**admin_panel**');
   define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . WP_ADMIN_DIR);
   ```
2. Add below filter to functions.php

   ```
   add_filter('site_url',  'wpadmin_filter', 10, 3);    
   function wpadmin_filter( $url, $path, $orig_scheme ) {    
       $old  = array( "/(wp-admin)/");    
       $admin_dir = WP_ADMIN_DIR;     
       $new  = array($admin_dir);    
       return preg_replace( $old, $new, $url, 1);   
   }
   ```
3. Add below line to .htaccess file

   ```
   RewriteRule ^admin_panel/(.*) wp-admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
   ```

And you are done.

Now your admin URL will be like: http://www.yourdomain.com/**admin_panel**/

Hope this help.

Comment: Is it still a working solution? Trying to make it work on localhost WP > 5.0