# htaccess file url rewriting issues using WordPress and PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My problem is I am adding a `RewriteRule` in a WordPress htaccess file, to prevent wp-admin from being accessed.

I receive this error:

> www.mywebsite.in redirected you too many times. Try clearing your
>   cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Please help me find a solution.

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^questionlistshow-(.*).html$ ./questionlistshow.php?url=$1 

# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule  ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
# file path
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mywebsite.in/404.html

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: For starters only use one "RewriteEngine On", it can fire twice in your code. Just use the one in the IfModule and move the first two rewrite rules to the end of that IfModule condition. This won't fix your problem but at least clean things up.

Comment: Thanks for reply 

according to remove last two end line

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, you need to word your question better. I'm assuming that you want to change your wp-admin path completely so that http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/ becomes http://yoursite.com/someothername/ for example? If so then check this solution out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141168/hiden-wp-admin-use-htaccess

Comment: Hi thanks for replay, ----- Now I will try this solution link and then reply stackoverflow.com/questions/27141168/.........but according to me  i think problem is (index,php) path file /.......

Comment: Tried to make your question make sense. Double check if I changed the meaning and edit to fix if needed.